# sum 2 table got loop sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT brg_laku.id_brg, SUM( brg_laku.dibeli ) AS sold, SUM( stok_brg.stok ) AS stock
FROM brg_laku, stok_brg
WHERE stok_brg.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
GROUP BY stok_brg.id_brg, brg_laku.id_brg
```

**This my sold table:**

```
id_bl id_brg     dibeli harga_laku tgl        jam 
   10 BRG-000001      2      30000 2018-03-16 10:48:35
   11 BRG-000001      1      35000 2018-03-16 10:48:38
   12 BRG-000003      5      30000 2018-03-16 10:48:41
   13 BRG-000003      4      35000 2018-03-16 10:47:13
```

**This is the view using code above:**

[image: this view from code above]

**This my stok table:**

[image: this my stok table]

How to make it sum correctly in SQL?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *as text in the question*.  How does anyone out here know what the "correct sum" is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the result  sum

```
SELECT brg_laku.id_brg, t.sum_stock
    , SUM( brg_laku.dibeli ) AS sold
 FROM brg_laku
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
  stok_brg.id_brg ,
  SUM( stok_brg.stok ) sum_stok
  FROM stok_brg
 )   t on t. id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg 
 group by brg_laku, t.sum_stock
```

Comment: can u explain  t.sum_stock column
cause i don't have that column in my table

Comment: "t on t. " what it's mean

Comment: @ViviNovitaSari   ..  t is an table name alias  add for  assign a table name at the inner join subquery . sum_stock is a column name alias  assigned for make the subselect sum result easly accessible once the inner join is estabilshed .. hope this commen is clear  ..  let me know